# Is it safe to plug guitar directly to portable (battery powered rechargeable) speaker

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, speakers

This is more of a technical questions but it relates to music practice, still, feel free to comment if you think it doesn’t belong here.

I bought a 6.3mm female 3.5mm male jack adapter and did the most naive/simple setup. Electro acoustic guitar->cable->adapter->portable speaker (jbl charge 3)
And it works fine, my only concern is will this damage the speaker?

[image: photo1] [image: photo2]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the rated output impedance of your guitar against the rated input impedance of your speaker.  'nuff said.

Comment: And how do they have to be relative to each other? The output impedance has to be lower or higher than the input impedance?

Comment: Is the adapter a Tip Ring Sleeve or Tip Ring plug?  It may not matter, but I would like to try the same thing. The way to tell TRS is look for three sections on the prong of the plug separated by black insulators.

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't harm the speaker at all.  The worst that could happen is weak and/or distorted sound, but even that doesn't mean you're damaging the speaker.

I'm surprised you said it works fine, unless the guitar has some sort of pre-amp built in to get the signal up to line level.  (My basses have passive pickups which are microphone level.) If that's the case then you could just as easily plug it into your computer's line in jack and have that work too.